# How to upload a file in Robot Framework?

Tags: file-upload, robotframework, autoit

I tried "choose file" but it is not working. I am not sure what to set 2nd argument to. I tried changing the different paths of file folder; it then navigates to the correct location but it's not selecting the text file or image in that location.

```
Choose File xpath   ${path}
```

So I want to use AutoIt but I don't know how to combine it with Selenium, how to write code and where to keep the AutoIt script.

Comment: I am getting AssertionError in absent of locator

Comment: You should provide locator of input field as first argument and path to file as second argument.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code for your `<input ..../>`?

Comment: I have tried with giving input field and path in that case i am getting below error

Comment: ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible  i am getting this error

Comment: Hi kootstra, first i need to click create button below that i need to click files and then windows location ill get open

Answer (score 2):

Here you need to give two arguments

1. Web-element locator of the Browse button or link where you want to upload the file (locators like id, name xpath, css are user)
2. then give the complete file path of the file you want to upload for Ex: If you file is in desktop and name of the file is fileName.txt then you path will be C:\Users\your_username\Desktop\fileName.txt (you can also use relative path of the file)

one such example line of code would be

```
1. Choose File  ${xpath_locator}  C:\Users\your_username\Desktop\fileName.txt
2. Chose File ${xpath_locator} ${file_path_variable}
```

where the ${file_path_varibale} taken from variable table of robot file.

you can explore more on all the Selenium Keywords in Robot Framework [Here.](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Choose%20File)

Comment: i have already tried all this method but i am getting error only

Comment: Can you paste the exact code what you are trying?? so that i can help you precisely

Answer (score 0):

It's better way to get Project Path and join it with your specific upload folder. After that just put the location with file name :)

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to write C: then image file ex. C:\image.jpg

Choose file    xpath    C:\yourImageofYourFile.jpg